# How can I root Lg K317 (Phoenix 2

Tags: root-access

I see that One Click Root say that it can root Lg K371 but I don't really know if it really .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [kingroot](https://kingroot.en.uptodown.com/android). It doesn't work the first time you try, it need several tries.